# Hidden attribute in Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I haven't used Polymer since the 0.4-0.5 era and am used to using the hidden attribute like so `<my-element hidden="{{foo != bar}}"></my-element>`

Now in Polymer 1.0 I see that have to use computed values from a method for anything that is not straight up a boolean value.
I have my code like this:

`<my-element hidden="{{_computeHidden()}}"></my-element>`

And then in the script section:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'super-element',
    properties: {...},
    _computeHidden: function(){
         console.log('its being called, mkay');
         return !(foo == bar);
    }
});
```

Now in the console the message comes up twice after page refresh but when the value of `foo` changes, the element does not disappear. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

So, there are two issues. As Maria notes, you have to have your `_computeHidden` method bound to parameters that will respond to Polymer notifications. So, both `foo` and `bar` must be declared as properties on the element.

Another issue is that "hidden" is a [boolean attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#boolean-attributes), meaning that its very presence indicates that the element should be hidden. In Polymer 1.0, using `$` in `hidden$=` changes hidden into a property binding and will handle strings. Without `$`, `hidden=` will evaluate just raw boolean. `hidden` is not on the list for required `$` in native html attributes, so the choice is up to you.

```js
Polymer({
    is: 'my-element',
    properties: {
      foo: Boolean,
      bar: Boolean
    },
    _computeHidden: function(){
      return !(this.foo == this.bar);
    }
});
```

```html
<my-element hidden$="{{_computeHidden(foo, bar)}}"></my-element>
```

With this [annotated attribute binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding), "hidden" will appear on the element only if your computed value is truthy, which is the behavior you want. With a simple "=" binding, "hidden" will appear even if your function returns true, or null, or any other value.

Comment: Huge thanks for `"hidden" will appear on the element only if your computed value is truthy` I was trying to figure out how to conditionally apply an attribute all afternoon and the docs are apparently wrong.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to trigger the recalculation of your function when `foo` changes, you have to ensure that `foo` is property and pass it into the function as an argument. Here's a small example.

```
<dom-module id="register-me">
    <template>
        <div hidden$="{{compute(ishidden)}}">Hello from my local DOM</div>
        <button on-click="toggle">Toggle Hidden</button>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({is: "register-me",
            properties: { ishidden: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false
            } },
            compute: function() {
                console.log("computing...");
                return this.ishidden;
            },
            toggle: function() {
                this.ishidden = !this.ishidden;
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Note that to bind to attributes, you should use `$=`.

Comment: Why the move from that simple syntax to this? Definitely seems a lot more cumbersome to me at least.

Comment: I don't know. Some things were changed for performance reasons. As far as expressions are concerned, it is possible that we will get them back some time in the future. I hope we will.

Comment: You don't need all of this. I added another answer -- you just need the "$=" part.

Comment: Conversely, it's also untrue that one should _always_ use `$=`. Use it only for binding boolean attributes.

Comment: @EricNguyen I disagree. If you omit the argument to the function, it will only evaluate once. So if you want to reevevaluate it when properties change, you have to pass them as arguments (see [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#dependent-properties)).

Comment: It is also not true that `$=` is for boolean attributes only. Rather it is for all attribute bindings (as opposed to property bindings). You would also use it for `class` or `href`, for example. Again, have a look at the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding/)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs. That was clarifying, but the accurate answer is somewhere in between. What you mean to say, I think, is that `$=` is not just for "boolean attributes" but also anywhere where "native bindings" are required (e.g. "style" and "class"). Here's a more-precise [link](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#native-binding) into the docs. 

You're also right about the dynamic binding. I'll update my answer to be a clear example for Najm.

Comment: With your updates, I have no more objections and I upvoted your answer.